# How to use echarts to zoom time axis?

Tags: echarts

I want to use echarts to zoom time axis(X axis) and Y axis.But I don not know how to do it,what attribute to add can zoom X axis and Y axis?

**I mean, when my left mouse's button selects a part of the X axis, I should zoom  the selected part.**

You can use my code to test.Now my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%">
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body style="height: 100%; margin: 0">
   <div id="container" style="height: 100%"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://echarts.baidu.com/gallery/vendors/echarts/echarts.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://echarts.baidu.com/gallery/vendors/echarts-gl/echarts-gl.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://echarts.baidu.com/gallery/vendors/echarts-stat/ecStat.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://echarts.baidu.com/gallery/vendors/echarts/extension/dataTool.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://echarts.baidu.com/gallery/vendors/echarts/map/js/china.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://echarts.baidu.com/gallery/vendors/echarts/map/js/world.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=2.0&ak=ZUONbpqGBsYGXNIYHicvbAbM"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://echarts.baidu.com/gallery/vendors/echarts/extension/bmap.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://echarts.baidu.com/gallery/vendors/simplex.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
var dom = document.getElementById("container");
var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
var app = {};
option = null;
option = {
    title: {
        text: 'Importance',
        left: 'center',
        top: '100'
    },
    tooltip: {
        trigger: 'axis'
    },

    grid: {
        left: '20%',
        right: '20%',
        top: '20%',
        bottom: '20%',
        containLabel: true
    },
    toolbox: {
        feature: {
            saveAsImage: {}
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        boundaryGap: false,
        data: ['2018week1','2018week2','2018week3','2018week4','2018week5','2018week6','2018week7','2018week8','2018week9','2018week10']
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'value'
    },
    series: [
        {
            name:'peter',
            type:'line',
            data:[1889,2930,2059,1948,1814,2071,2183,3234,3426,2188]
        },
        {
            name:'kate',
            type:'line',
            data:[875,694,919,1092,815,1137,1421,1547,1737,1748]
        }
    ]
};
;
if (option && typeof option === "object") {
    myChart.setOption(option, true);
}
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**The running effect of my code：**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting any `datazoom` option.

See https://echarts.apache.org/en/api.html#action.dataZoom